# Modelling the height of the marble on Uranus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

> The planet Uranus is known to have an acceleration due to gravity of $9ms^{-2}$ Imagine a marble is launched vertically into the air from a slingshot that releases the marble at a height of $2$ meters. After 2 seconds, its velocity is $31 m/s$. Find a function that models the height of the marble (in meters), t seconds after the initial launch (neglect air resistance).

So I thought I was given $a(t) = 9$, but the solution says that it is $a(t) = -9$, which I don't understand. Then I can get $v_0$ by solving $v(2)=31$, which results in $v(t) = -9t + 49$. But then I don't know how to get $h(t)$ from there...

Answer (score 1):

The "standard frame of reference" for vertical, one-dimensional motion states that up is the positive direction and down is the negative direction, and the zero point is arbitrary. The question's phrase "an acceleration due to gravity of $9\,\mathrm{ms^{-2}}$" refers to the *magnitude* of the acceleration. Since we know that gravity pulls down and the acceleration vector is down we say that $a$ is a constant $-9\,\mathrm{m/s^2}$. Other frames are possible and are sometimes useful, but I teach my physics students to use the standard frame of reference almost always.

You want to model the height with a formula using constant acceleration (I am using your notation rather than the one I usually use):

$$h = h_0 + v_0t + \frac 12at^2$$

But first you use the equation

$$v = v_0 + at$$

At $t=2$ you have $v=31$ and you already know $a$, so

$$31 = v_0 + (-9)2$$

Solving this gives

$$v_0 = 49$$

which is consistent with the equation you found for $v$ (look at my second equation). The question tells you that $h_0 = 2$. So now put all that information you now have for $h_0, v_0, a$ to get your final equation for $h$. I'll leave that last step to you.

Note that I use the commonly-known equations of constant acceleration to solve this problem. This can also be done from scratch, using integration twice from constant acceleration to get the equations for velocity and position.